# jQuery $[data] variable

Tags: jquery

I am very new to JavaScript. I was reading the source code of deck.js and found there a variable referred to as $[data].  What does this exactly mean?  I know that it refers to a jQuery variable because of the $ but what kind of a variable is it?  Is it an array of length data?

Thanks in advance,
kop

Answer (score 4):

The `$` doesn't necessarily mean that it refers to jQuery. There are many libraries that use the $ as an alias for their object.

And because JavaScript objects are associative arrays, `$[data]` is just another way to access a properly of the `$` object. For example, the following two pieces of code would return the same value:

```
var data = "someProperty";
alert($[data]);
```

and

```
alert($.someProperty);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So $ is somewhat like the this keyword?  A placeholder for any object?

Comment: @user1484503 - No. Not quite. `$` is just another variable since `$` by itself is a legal variable name in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The $ is an object.

Here is a simple Js object example:

```
var person=new Object();

person["name"] = "joe";

alert(person.name);
alert(person["name"]);
var data = "name";
alert(person[data]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KPV9N/1/

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will have to look into it a little more :)